# Ruby equivalent of PHP's ucfirst() function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

What's the best way in Ruby (with Rails, if relevant) to capitalize the first letter of a string?

Note that `String#capitalize` is not what I want since, in addition to capitalizing the first letter of the string, this function makes all other characters lowercase (which I don't want -- I'd like to leave them untouched):

```
>> "a A".capitalize
=> "A a"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use "sub" to get what you want (note: I haven't tested this with multibyte strings)

```
"a A".sub(/^(\w)/) {|s| s.capitalize}
```

(and you can of course monkeypatch String to add this as a method if you like)

Answer (score 17):

In Rails you have the `String#titleize` method:

"testing string titleize method".titleize #=> "Testing String Titleize Method"

Comment: Be aware that `titleize` makes other changes, such as inserting a space into [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) words.

Answer (score 6):

Upper case the first char, and save it back into the string

```
s = "a A"
s[0] = s[0,1].upcase
p s # => "A A"
```

Or,

```
class String
  def ucfirst!
    self[0] = self[0,1].upcase
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify the original string, you can do it this way:

```
class String
  def ucfirst
    str = self.clone
    str[0] = str[0,1].upcase
    str
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following solution, works through whitespace

```
'  ucfirstThis'.sub(/\w/, &:capitalize)
# => "UcfirstThis"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since rails 5:

```
"a A".upcase_first
=> "A A"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-upcase_first

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a real similar function to PHPs `ucfirst()` try

```
"a A".gsub(/(\w+)/) {|s| s.capitalize}
```

will result in "`A A`".

```
"a neW APPROACH".gsub(/(\w+)/) {|s| s.capitalize}
```

will result in "`A New Approach`".

You can extend String class with:

```
class String
  def ucfirst
    self.gsub(/(\w+)/) { |s| s.capitalize }
  end

  def ucfirst!
    self.gsub!(/(\w+)/) { |s| s.capitalize }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

[capitalizing-first-letter-of-each-word](http://bhanu.blogspot.com/2007/03/capitalizing-first-letter-of-each-word.html)

There's not an inbuilt function. You need to split the letters and rejoin or try Rails' String#titleize and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That one liner does not depend on ActiveSupport. Not sure it's totally bulletproof though:

```
"my great uncle and grand-ma".gsub(/(\A\w|\s\w)/) { |m| m.upcase }
# My Great Uncle And Grand-ma
```