# Does Ruby or Rails have a method to capitalize the first character only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Or it seems like I have to write my own method?  (to keep the `DHA` untouched):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > s = 'omega-3 (DHA)'
 => "omega-3 (DHA)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > s.capitalize
 => "Omega-3 (dha)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > s.titleize
 => "Omega 3 (Dha)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > s[0].upcase + s[1..-1]
 => "Omega-3 (DHA)"
```

Comment: Your last case is the easiest way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby equivalent of PHP's ucfirst() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479946/ruby-equivalent-of-phps-ucfirst-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apologies if my answer is just rubbish (I don't do ruby).
But I believe I've found an answer for you:

[Ruby equivalent of PHP's ucfirst() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479946/ruby-equivalent-of-phps-ucfirst-function)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a gsub with a regex that matches the first character of each word and replaces it with the uppercase character:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > 'omega-3 (DHA)'.gsub(/\b\w/){ $&.upcase }
 => "Omega-3 (DHA)"
```

[Oh... but that's overly complicated if you just want the first character of the string... the gsub will do the first character of each word. `s[0] = s[0].upcase` would work just fine.]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.titleize**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) or **.titlecase** for capitalize the first letter of the word.

ex:-
"manish anand".titleize => Manish Anand
"manish anand".titlecase => Manish Anand

Or you can use

"manish anand"**.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')** => Manish Anand

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have a method with the exact behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, for simple uses like this, I'd use:

```
s[0] = s[0].upcase
```

Comment: in Ruby 1.8.7, seems like it has to be  `s[0].chr.upcase`

Comment: Yes. 1.9+ returns the character. < 1.9 returned the ordinal value requiring the use of .chr.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 added this; it's called [`upcase_first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-upcase_first).

In Rails 4 or before, add this to a string extension.

```
class String

  def upcase_first
    self.sub(/\S/, &:upcase)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not have a method to capitalize the first character only (and leave all other letters alone). You have to use your own solution like your fourth example.

Comment: Yes it does, it is called .humnize

Answer (score 0):

.humanize comes close, but it downcaseses the rest of the string. I think the Tin Man's answer is the simplest.

```
s[0] = s[0].upcase
```